# How can I access the CSS style of the popup control with LocalDateTimePicker

Tags: css, javafx, jfxtras

I am using the `LocalDateTimeTextField` control of **JFxtras** but the popup that owns the `LocalDateTimePicker` is not assuming the styles of my custom CSS and I am not able to access the CSS style of that popup.

I found the styles of each of the controls but could not customize the styles of the controls present in the popup.
https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/tree/8.0/jfxtras-controls/src/main/resources/jfxtras/internal/scene/control

How can I access the CSS style of the popup control with `LocalDateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. The caveat is that LocalDate and LocalDateTime controls internally use the corresponding Calendar controls (and then convert the resulting type). So the styling for the popup can be found here.

https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/8.0/jfxtras-controls/src/main/resources/jfxtras/internal/scene/control/CalendarTextField.css